# gentoo crontab: why this simple crontab is not working?

Tags: linux, cron, gentoo

I use a GENTOO distribution.

crontab -e

```
35 12  * * *    root    php5 /home/www/cron.php
```

When I run manually:

```
php5 php5 /home/www/cron.php
```

This works (it sends me an email)

Then I check date
at 12:35pm... nbothing !

I also tried with:

```
*/1 * * * *     root    php5 /home/www/cron.php
```

So it sends me an email every minute and NOTHING !

I also tried with full path of php5

```
*/1 * * * *     root    /usr/local/bin/php5 /home/www/cron.php
```

Looks like crontab does not work: any idea why ?
What do I do wrong ?

regards

Comment: Please try specifying the php5 executable full path (ie /use/bin/php5) and tell us how it goes.

Comment: I JUST DID !!!
and still bad : 
*/1 * * * *     root    /usr/local/bin/php5 /home/www/cron.php

and of course when luching : /usr/local/bin/php5 /home/www/cron.php IT WORKS !

Comment: If you get an email, the cron job works. What's in the email? Presumably an error message? Please include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use in `crontab -e` does not allow you to specify the user name; it always runs as yourself.

So, the `root` is a syntax error (it causes Cron to try to run the command `root`, which probably does not exist); take it out and try again.

If you need the job to run as root, put the file (now *with* the user name) in `/etc/cron.d/`.